# Problema con el button de bootstrap en html para copiar al portapapeles

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Buenas tengo un problema con un boton que estoy haciendo para copiar al portapapeles con bootstrap, ya que aunque el boton funcione copia todo el texto del codigo en lugar de lo que yo quiero que copia
Aca esta el código

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Touch</button>`

Comment: Y el codigo???.

Comment: Agrega un [example]

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia soy nuevo como puedo hacer para ejecutar el codigo aqui directamente

Comment: Haz clic en el botón [edit] de tu pregunta, luego presiona en tu teclado `CONTROL + M` para que abras el Snippet y puedas agregar tu código ejecutable. Para más información revisa: [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet)